# Run ISM Policy Opensearch with query

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

i want to create policy to delete logs base on "expired_time" field in index.
Example:

index: my-log

data:

{
"logText":"message text",
"expired_time": "2024-02-01T14:33:33.290+00:00"
}

As i research, it can only be deleted by pattern index. So anyway i can process it?

Using: opensearch 1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

There was a [_ttl field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/mapping-ttl-field.html) to delete documents after the retention period. But the feature is removed.

> The _ttl mappings have been removed. As a replacement for _ttl
> mappings, we recommend using ILM (ISM in Opensearch) to create time-based indices.

### What you can do?

You can use _delete_by_query API to remove documents older than `X` times. It can make sense to trigger this query per hour.

An example:

```
POST index_name/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "expired_time": {
        "lt": "now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions bros, so anyway I can trigger this query base on Opensearch's scheduler or i have to create a scheduler in my code to run this query?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to add a trigger inside of Opensearch, if so please let me know. And yes one of the solutions is to trigger this query inside of your code.